# How to convert numeric values to text in sql for select query

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.1

I have string values like this

```
'[123, 124]'
```

I could trim the value using below command

```
select trim('[123, 124]', '[]'); --returning '123, 124' as text
```

I want to pass the value above as

```
select * 
from mytable 
where numeric_column in (select trim('[123, 124]', '[]'));
```

I can understand, `numeric_column` is numeric. But the inner query is returning the data as text. I could not convert the inner query to `numeric` since it has a comma.  If I want to convert the result to `'123', '124'`, I could run the following command and get the expected result:

```
select * 
from mytable 
where numeric_column::text in (
    select func_to_change(select trim('[123, 124]', '[]'))
);
```

How can I achieve this? What is the `func_to_change` logic I need to write?

Note: I am using Postgresql 9.1.

Comment: In the first place, why are you storing numbers as text?  Furthermore, you could replace the `[]` with `{}` and then cast it to `numeric[]`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Once you have removed the `[` and `]` you can use `string_to_array()` to convert the list to an array of integers. This can be used directly in the `where` clause:

```
select * 
from mytable 
where numeric_column = ANY(string_to_array(trim('[123, 124]', '[]'),',')::numeric[])
```

Answer (score -4):

Simply,

from

```
123, 124
```

to

```
'123','124'
```

You can use `String_agg` function